# Is there a way to clear the cache used by UIImage class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching, uiimage

It is well known that UIImage caches its image data when the image is loaded using the `imageNamed:` method.

From apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-imagenamed

> **imageNamed:**
>
> *Discussion*: This method looks in the
>   system caches for an image object with
>   the specified name and returns that
>   object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the
>   cache, this method loads the image
>   data from the specified file, **caches**
>    **it**, and then returns the resulting
>   object.

Because of that, after loading several images with `imageNamed:` I noticed a large increase of memory usage  and also that the memory was kept in use even after the controller that loaded the images was dealloc. (at least it didn't increase again when I alloc the same controller)

That made me wonder if there is any way to clear the cache used by UIImage programmatically at any given time of my application lifecycle or even control some cache parameters (like the maximum memory that it can use, for example)

I know that I could easily solve this problem by using `initWithData`, `imageWithData`, `imageWithContentsOfFile` or any other initializer instead of `imageNamed`, but this cache behavior is desired when using several images, like inside a `UITableView`.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish that?

EDIT:
After some answers I just want to make it clear that there is a huge gap between needing to do something and having the possibility to do something. As I pointed out, I know that the OS takes care of that cache for me, I am just trying to see the limitations that the iOS SDK imposes.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the edit was new...the only way I know to manually clear the cache is through an undocumented, private method, so I suppose it's not really possible.

Comment: @KevinLow really? what method is that? I could be nice to play with that! private API rules do not apply for ad hoc only apps ;)

Comment: Haha, it's a class method on UIImage. `[UIImage _flushSharedImageCache];` There's also `[image removeFromCache];` as well as `[UIImage removeImageNameFromCache:@"imageName"];`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908131/how-to-clear-ios-app-library-cache-downloaded-images/14910128#14910128

Comment: @Rajneesh071 good answer, but it appears that the cache that `UIImage` uses when the `imageNamed:` method is called is a memory cache, and not a file disk one (as it would make no sense, as the images from `imageNamed:` are already a file in the app bundle, differently from images loaded with `imageWithData:` and other similar methods). So the `_flushSharedImageCache` clears the allocated memory used by the images in cache, reducing the number of memory warnings in a heavy memory usage app (which was initially my intention by the time I asked this). But tks anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer taken from [Kevin Low](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144689/kevin-low) comment

---

If you can use *private APIs* (as in an AdHoc only app, for example) use this [`UIImage` method](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/7ef0330f961248b9021e59e12aa3182440194817/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIImage.h#L56) to remove all images from cache

```
[UIImage _flushSharedImageCache];
```

Comment: there are no such method for UIImage.

Comment: @Curnelious Thanks for the feedback, I removed the ones that really didn't exist and also added a link to the private UIImage headers file pointing to the one I left in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way I know of to manually clear this iOS managed cache. In general, this is a red herring. When the os manages something for you, you don't need to worry about it. As long as you are correctly releasing anything you alloc/retain and handling memory warnings appropriately you're doing your part.

Comment: There is a huge gap between *needing to do something* and *having the possibility to do something*. As I pointed out in my question, I know there I don't **need** to do it, as I can use `initWithData` to create images, I am just trying to see the limitations that the SDK imposes.

Comment: My point was that you shouldn't be worrying about the memory in use by an os managed cache. It is fair to worry about the in memory needs of your app and manage anything you are storing or caching yourself. The os will manage it's caches as needed and that implementation is opaque to you unless Apple documents and recommends otherwise. You certainly can use initWithData and implement your own image cache (or not). It's hard to imagine what situation that would be better.

Comment: Reason aside, if you want 100% control over image caching I would implement your own cache and never use `imageNamed:`.

Comment: Sorry for bombarding you, wanted to add one more thing. I answered the way I did b/c in your question you indicated that the image caching behavior of iOS is a "problem" that you need to solve. It is not a problem and any memory allocated by the OS for this cache is the responsibility of the OS, not a problem you need to worry about. If you are running into a problem where your app requires too much memory to run the problem is not in the image cache. You can assume the OS will flush this cache appropriately in low memory conditions.

Comment: @XJones If you app crashes due to memory problems - the user isn't going to blame the OS, they're going to condemn your app! So you might be doing your part - but the user is oblivious to this.

Comment: Not sure what your point is. A well built iOS app should never crash for any reason. My answer is specific to this question (UIImage class internal implementation). An app that doesn't manage it's resources efficiently (crash or not) is a poor app. Worrying about how UIImage works internally isn't something a dev needs to be concerned about.

Comment: UIImage caching simply works bad and it's a pain even with ARC. I can flush entire view controllers and storyboard and still the memory isn't free by iOS.

Comment: well the OS does it clearly wrong, as i have a keyboard app, that crashes by exceeding 50MB of memory... i display only 10 images at a time, but using imageNamed and withtout the option to flush the cache my app crashes... so much for "you dont need to worry about As long as you are correctly releasing" ... only 10 images are assigned at a time, but the system still holds them all and crashes

Answer (score -1):

The cache will be emptied when it needs to be, i.e. when the application receives a Low Memory Warning. There is no reason for you to do this yourself, and there is no public API available.

Comment: I wont argue about reason, as I already explained in the other answer's comment. But, do you know how it is done, even with a private API? (as my app is ad-hoc distributed, there is no worry about being rejected by apple store)

Comment: There is pretty good reason: My app's memory usage is not high enought to trigger memory warning but still high. After rotation more memory get's alocated and the app is killed due to "memory error" without memory warning. If I could free cache memory before rotation, app would nicelly survive the rotation.... No public API == no options.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe we have more then one methods for delete cached images, but i think you can used self.cache.removeAllObjects() which is one of the more methods if you use Cache() object.If i am wrong everybody can corrected me