# how to get URL Path for directory inside Document directory?

Tags: iphone, directory, nsfilemanager

How can I get url path for a particular directory inside Document Directory.

like `Document/Art/`

My code

```
- (NSURL *)localRoot {
if (_localRoot != nil) {
    return _localRoot;
}

NSArray * paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

_localRoot = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return _localRoot;
}
```

The above code is  url path for  `Documents` directory but I need `Art` document directory path.

Comment: follow my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908131/how-to-clear-ios-app-library-cache-downloaded-images/14910128#14910128

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *yourArtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Art"];
```

Comment: - (NSURL *)localRoot {
    
    if (_localRoot != nil) {
        return _localRoot;
    }
    
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSString *artdirectoryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Art"];
    
    _localRoot=[NSURL URLWithString:artdirectoryPath];
    
    return _localRoot;
}
  this my updated Code but still i got error..

Comment: while go to path  -[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:]: URL is nil'

Comment: When we use path component then there is no need to add "/" with component

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *appFile_a = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Art"];
```

Comment: its NSString i need NSURL  so which method i will use insed of stringByAppendingPathComponent:

Comment: add this line also NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:appFile_a];

Comment: NSString *appFile_a = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@\"Art\"]; have bug at `@"\Art"\`

Answer (score 0):

**Application.StartupPath;**

is used to find your path where your application is being started, if that is what you mean.

Comment: sorry i am beginner i got this url while running /Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8A1E5A56-F85B-4128-83F9-208643469DB3/Documents

Answer (score 0):

Based on above answer here is an simple methode that returns, path for given directory:

```
+ (NSString *) pathFor : (NSString *) directoryName{
    return [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryName];
}
```

You need to implement it in `ClassName.m` and call as:

```
NSString *pathForDirectory = [ClassName pathFor:dirName]; //@"Art" in your case
```