# Playing sound with AvPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to play sound with AvPlayer. I am using following method:

```
func playSound() {
    let coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("voiceRecord", ofType: "caf")!)
    do{
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:coinSound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch {
        print("Error getting the audio file")
    }
}
```

**I am sure I have voiceRecord.caf file in my app's Documents folder.** I am getting following error for first line.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How to resolve?

Comment: This is not a npe question. As i said in my question: I am sure I have voiceRecord.caf file in my app's Documents folder.

Comment: Your app's `Documents` folder is not the same place as the app's main bundle.

Comment: So how to go Documents folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14938137/312594 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638834/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-documents-folder?rq=1

Comment: Verify that `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("voiceRecord", ofType: "caf")` does not return `nil`.  If it does, this is a dupe.  That is the only place where you are force-unwrapping an optional value.  Please read the linked question.