# iOS app crashing on loading UIImage due to memory issues

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, memory-leaks, uiimage

My question is extremely similar to [iOS Application Crash while UIImage loading (virtual memory not cleaning up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805737/ios-application-crash-while-uiimage-loading-virtual-memory-not-cleaning-up?noredirect=1&lq=1)
in that I have an array of objects, and each object has a picture as one of it's variables. The answer in the above post seems to be that the objects remain even after they were removed from the array. However I cannot seem to figure out exactly what he did to fix this issue. I am using Swift, and have no experience in Objective-C.

**Could someone please tell me what he did to fix his issue? His sample code in the answer makes no sense to me.**

Here is my class, which includes the image property:

```
open class Cards {
    var name = ""
    var image : UIImage!
    var manaCost = 0
    var rarity = ""
    var whichClass = ""
    var cardText = ""
    var tribe = ""
    var cardType = "" //Minion or Spell
    var set = ""


    init(name : String,  image : UIImage!,  manaCost : Int, rarity : String, whichClass : String, cardType : String, tribe : String, cardText : String, set : String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.manaCost = manaCost
        self.rarity = rarity
        self.whichClass = whichClass
        self.cardType = cardType
        self.tribe = tribe
        self.cardText = cardText
        self.set = set
    }

    deinit {
         print("deinit " + name);
    }

}
```

The initialization of the objects looks a little something like this:

```
var ArgeonHighmayne = Cards(name: "Argeon Highmayne", image :  UIImage( named  : "ArgeonHighmayne")!, manaCost : 0, rarity : "Basic", whichClass : "Lyonar", cardType : "General", tribe : "None", cardText : "Bloodborn Spell: Give a minion nearby your general +2 Attack.", set : "Core")
```

and the arrays that these objects are placed in look like this:

```
public var newestCards = [DayWatcher, NightWatcher, DustWailer, QuartermasterGauj]
```

I have attempted to turn the objects themselves into weak references by simply adding "weak" before the declaration and adding all the "!" and "?"
that Xcode required me to add, but this just resulted in the images not appearing in my collection view. 
I also tried adding "weak" in the class declaration itself like so:

```
weak var image : UIImage!
```

But this also resulted in the images simply not showing up. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why do you declare `var ArgeonHighmayne` with a capital letter? is it a class or a var ?

Comment: @mat that is an instance of the class.

Comment: Are you sure you have file with a name "ArgeonHighmayne"? UIImage( named  : "ArgeonHighmayne")!

Comment: @Prabhu.Somasundaram yes, everything works fine other than it crashing due to memory filling up. It only doesn't show images when I changed it to weak. The link I provided will give a lot of info on how someone else solved the problem. I just need someone to help me understand their solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was crashing because the images were part of the array. Instead of putting a UIImage within the class, it is better to put the image's name there, and then call UIImage on that name in the collectionView method.