# Memory increase while scrolling through UITableview-Cells wont dellocated

Tags: uitableview, memory-leaks

I´ve a UiTableview with custom UITableviewcells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
AssortmentTableViewCell *cell = (AssortmentTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Breads *bread = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.breadName.text = bread.name;
cell.breadImageOutlet.image = [UIImage imageNamed:bread.breadimage];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
}
```

When I´m scrolling through the Tableview, the memory rises sharply. It seems, that the cells aren´t reuse. When the Tableview disappeares, the memory isn´t released. I work with IOS7/xcode5.

What could be the error?
For instructions I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you try commenting out this line and check if the memory rise is any different?                                          cell.breadImageOutlet.image = [UIImage imageNamed:bread.breadimage];

Comment: I commented out this line, now the memory increase is quite low. But the image is very important. Is there a possibility to do a low memory increase with the images? Also the Images are very big (500-700kb)..

Comment: Why are the images so big? Are these images not of thumbnail size? Big images of the size you mention should not be used in UITableView. You need to consider redesigning your app. Just use small sized thumbnails in tableview and have user tap the cell to show big image could be one way of achieving this.

Comment: My tableviewcells are very tall (about a size of 350). And the main part of the cells are the images. So i thought i have to use, images with a very good quality. But i try to resize the images, for a lower memory consumption. What is your advice, what are the best size of a picture, when i want to use a big thumbnail in my tableview? And should I use jpg or png? Many thanks for your efforts mithlesh jha!

Comment: It could possibly be 40 X 40, but is not hard and fast. You can define whatever size that you wish (and that you already have also), but the baseline is that tableview should ideally show small sized thumbnail and large sized images should go to detail screen associated with every cell that you can navigate to by tapping the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by UIKit caching the images, which is nothing to worry about, since the cache will be flushed if there is low memory. Does the memory use continue increasing indefinitely when scrolling up and down through the table view? If so then it is probably a fault in the implementation of AssortmentTableViewCell.

Comment: No the memory only increase when i scrolling down for the first time. When i scroll up and down the memory level stays the same. Is theres a possiblity to clean the cache?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986177/is-there-a-way-to-clear-the-cache-used-by-uiimage-class] suggests that you can clear individual images from the cache using `[image removeFromCache]` or `[UIImage removeImageNameFromCache:@"imageName"]`. Alternatively you can load the images using `imageWithContentsOfFile` instead of `imageNamed`. The OS should take care of cleaning the cache, so I wouldn't worry about it unless you are seeing a performance problem.