# How to release image in cache

Tags: caching, automatic-ref-counting, release, autorelease

When push to new ViewController , all image did loaded to cache. But when I pop to first View Controller ,this image don't release. So How to release all image.
Thank so much!

Comment: in which technology of CODE ?

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh : what is That technology ? . I know how to release them.

Comment: In which thing this problem is occurs in browser or any where else

Comment: I understood this issue. with [UIImage imageNamed:] ,I can't release images in cache, instead of I use imageWithContentsOfFile function.

Comment: If you use UIImage +imageNamed:, there are no way to release the cache except the private API. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5986177/629118

Comment: Thank Kazuki Sakamoto . I though so too.