# Is there a way to refresh the cache used by UIImage class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiimage

In my iOS app I am using the `+imageNamed:` method to load an image (*many times and in many different places in the code*).
In **one** case the user might update (download) a new image.
When I try to load the new, it will show the old, due to caching.
From the "[Is there a way to clear the cache used by UIImage class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986177/is-there-a-way-to-clear-the-cache-used-by-uiimage-class)"  question, I saw that I have to use the `-initWithContentsOfFile:` method.

But this will not take advantage of the caching speedup that the `+imageNamed:` enjoys. All I want is to "*tell*" the cache that the file has changed, so it needs to "*re-cache*" it. And then keep using the `+imageNamed:` method with the new cached image.

In other words, I use the `+imageNamed:` method (say) 10 times, I change the image, I "tell" the cache, then I continue use the `+imageNamed:` method another (say) 10 times. If I change all the `+imageNamed:` to `-initWithContentsOfFile:` then I lose the caching advantage.

Is there a way/trick to do that?

Comment: P.S. No private framework solutions please. My App goes to the AppStore, so I must use the "official" tools.

Comment: The question you linked already answers this question. Why did you post another one?

Comment: Why does it still display the old image? Do they have the same name?

Comment: Yes. The name is the same. I just overwrite the (old) file.

Comment: Can you just give it a unique name and delete the old file?

Comment: The question I linked *does not* answer *this* question. It says how to solve - a similar - problem. I know how to solve *that* problem. Mine is slightly different. (I want to take advantage of the cache, not discard it).

Comment: No. I have to use the same name (it is a rather large program... If I change the name, I have to re-wright / re-think a lot of code... I am looking for an easy way out...) ;-)

Comment: How are you using imageNamed on files downloaded by the user?

Comment: I just pass the ../Documents/name.png as its name. (when I started this App, more than 4 years ago, it was ... the only way I knew...) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably just have to figure out your own way of caching your images.

I'd suggest using a `UIImage` category with a static `NSMutableDictionary` that can hold your cached images. Then just use your custom caching method when initialising your `UIImage`.

For example:

```
@interface UIImage (UIImageCache)

+(UIImage*) cachedImageFile:(NSString*)imageFile;
+(void) resetCacheForImageFile:(NSString*)imageFile;

@end

@implementation UIImage (UIImageCache)

static NSMutableDictionary* cachedImages;

+(UIImage*) cachedImageFile:(NSString*)imageFile {

    // Optional error checking
    NSAssert1([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageFile], @"Warning! The image file %@ doesn't exist.", imageFile);

    if (!cachedImages) cachedImages = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    UIImage* cachedImg = [cachedImages objectForKey:imageFile];
    if (cachedImg) return cachedImg; // Image is cached, return it

    else { // No cached image, create one
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFile]; // iOS won't auto-cache the image.
        [cachedImages setObject:img forKey:imageFile];
        return img;
    }

}


+(void) resetCacheForImageFile:(NSString*)imageFile {
    [cachedImages removeObjectForKey:imageFile];
}

@end
```

Comment: Well... thanks for this... I was looking for something ... "less intrusive"... (I mean why re-invent the wheel if I already have one...). But thanks anyway...

Comment: Well I'm not sure you have many options... Apple is always quite protective over the inner workings of its SDK, so without using private methods, you can't do this through the SDK.

Comment: :-( ...
I am looking for a workaround or a way to trick the cache to re-load the file... (without messing with the "inner workings of the SDK")

Comment: Well even if you do manage to find a trick to reset the UIImage cache, there's no guarantee that it'll remain viable in future versions of iOS. This way is a lot more maintainable and transparent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for clearing the cache. If your app is not destined for the app store you could call the **private** method:

```
[UIImage _flushSharedImageCache];
```

However I wouldn't want this anywhere near production code.

Instead I would create a category on UIImage and add a method for returning the desired image from a filename. This name would be stored and then updated when your new image is downloaded. You will get the benefit of caching, without any hacky workarounds.

Depending on the complexity of your project, a simple find and replace shouldn't take too long.

Although I'm now questioning how your app is working currently, imageNamed only looks for files in your app's bundle, so won't work for images downloaded by the user.

Comment: Well if you're going to use a private method, then you might as well use the `_flushSharedImageCache` method on `UIImage`, from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23292184/2976878

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that, I'll update the answer.

Comment: That ("However I wouldn't want this anywhere near production code") is why I asked for a clean solution. That one I had seen in the linked question... :-(

Comment: There is no clean solution other than rewriting your code. Use originaluser2's method as this will work for downloaded images and imageNamed will not. (Have you tried your code on an actual device?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just got late to the party...but using

`+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *`

I got rid of the cache issue.

Hope it helps!!